# Comparison of raw block devices

Tags: hard-disk, dd, block-device

Is there a utility (or some shell magic) that allows me to compare two block devices?

Details: I have one large (0.5 TB) RAID device that I've backed up to a slightly larger SATA device using dd.  The device has several partitions on it, however I copy from the 'parent' device and not the partitioned device nodes (e.g., I copy /dev/hda and not /dev/hda1 for example).

I would like to verify that backup is good/correct.

I have thought about running md5sum across each device, however that won't give me an accurate result as the second device is slightly larger than the first and thus the extra bytes will change the hash.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would use the command

```
cmp /dev/hda /dev/hdb
```

it will stop at the first differing byte, writing out its offset, or on EOF on the shorter one.

Comment: I don't see in the manpage anything about stopping at EOF, is that documented somewhere?

Comment: In fact, the exit status says: "1: The  files  are different; this includes the case where one file
              is identical to the first part of the other." This seems to imply that it does not report them as identical if one is shorter.

Comment: @Kevin: from `info cmp`: "The 'cmp' command compares two files, and if they differ, tells the first byte and line number where they differ."

Comment: You can use the `--bytes=LIMIT` option, setting the `LIMIT` value to the bytesize of the smaller device to stop at the end of the smaller drive (or partition boundary) without having `cmp` exit with non-zero status.

Comment: if I have a copy /dev/loop0 of /dev/sda and I do changes to /dev/loop0, how could I add the new changes to /dev/sda ?? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for binary diff software

[rdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rdiff)
is designed for backup and network transmition, look at rdiff-backup and duplicity for backup propuse

[xdelta3](https://code.google.com/p/xdelta/wiki/CommandLineSyntax)
is an open-source binary diff, differential compression tools, VCDIFF (RFC 3284) delta compression.

bsdiff
is too!! memory hungry, is not suitable for block devices.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how full the drives actually are, it may be fastest to mount the file systems and do

```
diff -qr /mnt/root1 /mnt/root2
```

Otherwise, I would say something like this:

```
diff -q <(dd bs=1M count=500K if=/dev/sda) <(dd bs=1M count=500K if=/dev/sdb)
```

Obviously figure out just how big you need to make `bs` and `count` to stop at (or just before if it's much more convenient) the end of the smaller drive.

Or, thanks to enzotib's comment, it looks like you could use `cmp`, but you'll need the `-n` flag to limit the number of bytes to the shorter of the two drives.

```
cmp /dev/sda /dev/sdb -n 500GB
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to mount the device as its an NTFS volume, and I have a LiveCD without the right drivers on it.  For the second command the subshells you use don't try to suck the whole device into memory before feeding it into diff?

Comment: @alanxz No, the `diff` subshells will not read the entire device before writing it. `dd` writes `bs` bytes immediately after reading it (or processing if specified, not here), and they write to `fifo`s, which block until they're read.

Comment: I was thinking more at the shell level (or whatever implements the FIFO).  But that answers my question!

Answer (score 1):

There is an utility called [bsdiff](http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/), which does exactly this kind of thing. It does it really fast, and it's able to generate a binary patch, if you need.

See [this post](http://damaestro.us/blog/bsdiff-very-interesting-binary-diff) for some explanation around it.

Comment: `bsdiff`'s job is more complex than simply compare two files, so I doubt it can be faster than the simpler `cmp`.

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare two differently-sized block devices using `md5sum` like this:

(assuming the smaller device is `/dev/sda`)

```
# md5sum /dev/sda && head -c $(blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sda) /dev/sdb | md5sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider running `fsck` on the backup.   You may need to play some tricks with `losetup` to get loopback devices set on partitions embedded in the backup, but if the file check says the file structure is consistent the data itself is likely good.

If you want a full checksum, you can use loopback devices with offsets to look at the internal 'partitions' of the backup and md5sum each separately, but a forced `fsck` may give you a basic idea much faster than byte for byte compares or checksum computations.