# how to duplicate rootfs to another partition (dd cause problems)

Tags: dd, root-filesystem

I've been using dd in order to duplicate my rootfs into another partition and boot the system using the new rootfs copy.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk/by-partuuid/342853ea-cab9-4a4f-b935-1a704c1cc17f conv=sync,noerror bs=4M of=/dev/nvme0n1p1
```

where the partuuid is the rootfs partition part uuid.

The problem is that sometimes it seems like dd copies the rootfs with small corruptions.
(I'm getting corrupted files or dd is stucked)

Is there any other safer option I can use to do that?

Comment: You can do it with dd relibely only when filesystem is not mounted. You get inconsistent copy because filesystem is constantly changed while dd copying it's blocks

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I can confirm that the target filesystem is not mounted while I execute dd.    Is there any option for me to diff the original rootFS and the duplication after dd finishes?

Comment: cmp /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29921/comparison-of-raw-block-devices

Comment: thank you. I understand that you recommend dd. Sometimes it gets stuck. why it happen?

Comment: [dd conv sync noerror corrupts your data](https://superuser.com/a/1075837/195171), it's better to handle read errors with `ddrescue`

Comment: can you please specify the exact command?   dd conv sync ddrescue?  thats the command to use?

Comment: @hutcruchi No, i **don't recommend** dd or ddrescue in your case. Read updated answer. Errors and stucks maybe due bad blocks on source and/or target partitions.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that sometimes it seems like dd copies the rootfs with small corruptions. (I'm getting corrupted files or dd is stucked)

> OK, now I understand you meant both rootfs wont be mounted. The problem is that **its not possible since I'm using an embbeded system without usb** support.

**TLDR**
If source and/or target filesystems are **active** (mounted) duplicate (synchronize) them at filesystem level using `rsync` (locally or over network) or with plain `cp`.

**At block level**
You can safely copy (duplicate) filesystem at **block level**  (whole disk, partition, logical volume) only when **both filesystems** - on source and target block devices are **not mounted**.

You get inconsistent copy (broken filesystem) on target because:

- mounted filesystem on **source block device** is constantly change it's (meta)data and other internal structures while your program reading  blocks of underlying source block device
- additionally mounted filesystem on **target block device** is constantly reads and updates it's (meta)data and other internal structures while your program directly writing blocks to target block device bypassing OS. You confuse OS and programs running on target system because their in-memory state not consistent with filesystem's meta(data) and their may read wrong data and corrupt meta(data) by writes.

You should copy block device only when upper layers (mainly filesystems) are offline (unmounted, non active).

**At filesystem level**
This implies that filesystems are mounted.

Here you also may get inconsistency like with block device but only for data (logical level) stored on target filesystem if target or source files are updated while copying.
Running OS and applications may also be confused by replaced target files they work with.

With 100% guarantee you can copy only files opened for read on source system over files not opened for writes by OS or applications on target system.

You can copy files from mounted and active filesystem to another mounted and active filesystem but results may depends.

You can't just blindly copy files between devices with different hardware architecture, different filesystem hierarchy, different distributions and so on.

For copy at filesystem level you may use `rsync` (locally or over network) or just plain `cp`.

**You should not copy directories with runtime data specific to both systems** like: `/dev`, `/proc`, `/sys`, `/tmp`, `/run`, `/var/run`, `/var/tmp`, `/lost+found`, `/media`, `/mnt`, certain configuration files, running database files, and more, depending on how the target and source systems differ.

You may use lvm snapshots if your filesystem is on top of lvm logical volume and copy snapshot's files.

With xfs you may pipe output xfsdump /source_fs to xfsrestore /target_fs while source filesystem is online.

Comment: OK, now I understand you meant both rootfs wont be mounted. The problem is that its not possible since I'm using an embbeded system without usb support. Maybe there is another idea?

Comment: answer is updated

Answer (score 0):

If the source filesystem supports the freeze/thaw mechanism, then you can use it in the sequence (provided the target fs is NOT mounted) : 1/ freeze source fs, 2/ copy blocks with dd, 3/ thaw source fs.

While the source fs is frozen, no write access can't be made. Note that if your source fs is mounted with the 'atime' option even read access generate writes (to update the 'access time' metadata). Depending on your use case, it might be okay or not.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/fsfreeze suggests support for Linux Ext3/4, ReiserFS, JFS, XFS.

On a sidenote, you could have a COW fs (the same as source and destination) and use per-block incremental transfers with snapshots as reference points, like the btrfs send/receive mechanism (or ZFS). But I doubt you're having those kind of fs in an embedded context.